# Как посчитать количество checked checkbox в form у которых value=5

Tags: javascript, html

Как посчитать количество checked checkbox у input в form по value=5 а также отдельно у которых value=-2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
console.log(document.querySelectorAll("input[type='checkbox'][value='5']:checked").length);
```